# How to change font colour and size for only selected row and for unselected rows to be normal in table view in swift 3?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

Here I need to make selected row text to increase font,change colour and make underline like attributed text and this I had completed but here I need to make only selected cell text to be highlighted like with above told attributes and when I click on another row then I need to make remaining cells text to be normal without increase in font size,colour and make underline and remaining cells to be as normal can anyone help me how to implement this ?

[image]  [image]

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "categoriesTableCell", for: indexPath)  as! categoriesTableViewCell
    if indexPath.row == currentSelection {
        let item = categoriesModelClass?.childrenData[indexPath.row]
        cell.categoriesProductsLabel.font = UIFont(name:"Bold", size:17)
        cell.categoriesProductsLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
        let underlineAttribute = [NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue]
        let underlineAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: (item?.name)! , attributes: underlineAttribute)
        underlineAttributedString.addAttribute(NSUnderlineColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.cyan, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: (item?.name?.characters.count)!))
        cell.categoriesProductsLabel.attributedText = underlineAttributedString
    }
    else {
        let item = categoriesModelClass?.childrenData[indexPath.row]
        cell.categoriesProductsLabel.textColor = UIColor.darkGray
        cell.categoriesProductsLabel.text = item?.name
    }
    return cell
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let previousSelection = self.currentSelection
    self.currentSelection = indexPath.row
    if previousSelection == -1 {
        let index = indexPath
        let cell = self.sideTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! categoriesTableViewCell
        let item = categoriesModelClass?.childrenData[indexPath.row]
        cell.categoriesProductsLabel.font = UIFont(name:"Bold", size:17)
        cell.categoriesProductsLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
        let underlineAttribute = [NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue]
        let underlineAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: (item?.name)! , attributes: underlineAttribute)
        underlineAttributedString.addAttribute(NSUnderlineColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.cyan, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: (item?.name?.characters.count)!))
        cell.categoriesProductsLabel.attributedText = underlineAttributedString
        sideTableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)

    }else {

        let prevIndexPath = IndexPath(row: previousSelection, section: 0)
        self.sideTableView.reloadRows(at: [prevIndexPath,indexPath], with: .none)
    }

}
```

Comment: No need to change font in  `didSelectRowAt ` as you reload cell it will affect automatically

Answer (score 0):

Make integer value that represents currently selected row index and in cellForRowAt do this

```
  if(index != -1 )
    {
        if(index == indexPath.row)
        {

            cell.leftLb.font = UIFont.init(name: "Helvetica", size: 50)

       }
       else
       {
          cell.leftLb.font = UIFont.init(name: "Helvetica", size: 10)

        }

    }
```

When didSelectRow clicked update index and reload the table

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{


    index = indexPath.row

    self.areaSettTable.reloadData()


}
```

Comment: then this code should be placed in cell for row at index path to handle during reload

Answer (score 0):

**Use this code:**

**Set selection color**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
  let selectedCell:UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath)!
  selectedCell.categoriesProductsLabel.font = UIFont(name:"Bold", size:17)
  selectedCell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
}
```

**Set selection color**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
    let cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath)!
    cell.categoriesProductsLabel.font = UIFont(name:"*Set whatever you want here*", size:14)
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
}
```

Comment: I need after selecting a row it need to highlight like as shown that I got but when I select on another row then I need to highlight this row and the previously selected row needs to normal

Comment: Yes this code will work.Please check the updated code. You can change the colour according to your choice.

Answer (score 0):

try your same code with some changes below:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "categoriesTableCell", for: indexPath)  as! categoriesTableViewCell

  if indexPath.row == currentSelection {

  let item = categoriesModelClass?.childrenData[indexPath.row]
  cell.categoriesProductsLabel.font = UIFont(name:"Bold", size:17)
  cell.categoriesProductsLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
  let underlineAttribute = [NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue]
  let underlineAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: (item?.name)! , attributes: underlineAttribute)
  underlineAttributedString.addAttribute(NSUnderlineColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.cyan, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: (item?.name?.characters.count)!))
  cell.categoriesProductsLabel.attributedText = underlineAttributedString

  }else {

   let item = categoriesModelClass?.childrenData[indexPath.row]
   cell.categoriesProductsLabel.textColor = UIColor.darkGray
   cell.categoriesProductsLabel.font = UIFont(name:"Bold", size:10)
   cell.categoriesProductsLabel.text = item?.name

}
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    self.currentSelection = indexPath.row
    self.sideTableView.reloadData()

}
```

Comment: if I select one table view cell then the selected label is working fine with my posted code but when I change direction of selecting cells then it's not working properly @Shezad

Answer (score -1):

Initialize variable that holds current selection with -1 then as Cell is selected set row number as its value. Reload previous selection and current selection cell only. No need to reload whole tableview

```
let arrData:[String] = ["Woman's Clothing","Men's Clothing","Bags","Beauty","Sports","Shoes"]
var currentSelection = -1
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return self.arrData.count

}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
    cell?.textLabel?.text = self.arrData[indexPath.row]
    if indexPath.row == currentSelection {

        cell?.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.blue //Apply font, color for selected cell
    }else {

        cell?.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.black //Apply font, color for non selected cell
    }
    return cell!
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let previousSelection = self.currentSelection
    self.currentSelection = indexPath.row
    if previousSelection == -1 {

        self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)

    }else {

        let prevIndexPath = IndexPath(row: previousSelection, section: 0)
        self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [prevIndexPath,indexPath], with: .none)
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this logic?

Comment: but it fails during particular situation @Priya

Comment: I'm unable to get the issue by seeing image. Can you please elaborate the issue?

Comment: when I click one by one it was working perfectly but when I click consecutively then the font size was not changing to normal just see in my image @Priya

Comment: here I had edited my code just check it fails when u click consecutively like after selecting first row the click on third or fourth row then it fails @Priya

Comment: see in my image different font sizes of cell text @Priya

Comment: Have you set normal font size in else part ?

Comment: but when I click one by one rows it sets automatically but it fails when I done consecutively

Comment: `cell.categoriesProductsLabel.font = UIFont(name:"Bold", size:17)` as you have set this as selected cell on else part place `cell.categoriesProductsLabel.font = UIFont(name:"Normal", size:17)` or what ever you need as non selected text font